# Sources of these questions?

Tags: soft-question

I recently stumbled on preprint "36 unsolved problems in number theory", [ArXiv:math/0010143](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0010143).

and I was wondering what does 'Gamma $\underline{\phantom{abcbdbe}}$' refer to? (I'm interested in some of the questions but I'm not sure what should I do to look up further regarding some of these questions esp. those without references.

Thanks :)

Comment: Perhaps a [Romania (Brasov) 'journal'](http://www.scribd.com/doc/7832401/28/JUBILEE-OF-%E2%80%9CGAMMA%E2%80%9D-JOURNAL)

Answer (score 5):

Gamma is a Romanian school journal.  Smaradanche has made many contributions to it.

Comment: Ah 

Are you aware if the problems listed in the article are still unsolved and how should I go about to look further into these questions (considering that they don't have a name etc.)?

Comment: @user37864: I only looked briefly at the paper. Could maybe tell you about some specific number-theoretic problems.